# Handle empty array as nil in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

An empty array (`[]`) is handled as "true" in boolean contexts. Is there any smart way to handle an empty array as false?

I would like to make a simple code that lists C files in the current directory, or "Main.c" if no C file is in the directory. I can write like below, but is there any smarter way?

```
Dir.glob("*.c")!=[] ? Dir.glob("*.c").join(" ") : "Main.c"
```

Comment: `2.1.1 :001 > [].empty?
 => true 
` just call the `empty?` on an array and it will tell you if its empty :)

Answer (score 2):

I would write it this way, avoiding repeating the code that calls Dir.glob multiple times and using `Array#empty?`:

```
files = Dir.glob("*.c")
files.empty? ? 'Main.c' : files.join(' ')
```

Actually, this seems more consistent:

```
files = Dir.glob("*.c")
files = ['Main.c'] if files.empty?
files.join(' ')
```

Answer (score -1):

If you can assume that there is/should always be a "Main.c" in the results list, push it in and then uniq the list to eliminate duplicates if there are any.

```
[*Dir.glob("*.c"), "Main.c"].uniq.join(" ")
```